# UPDATE with Aggregate SELECT - SET columns 0 when SELECT is empty

Tags: postgresql

I have the following UPDATE statement

```
UPDATE stuff
SET stuff.total = t.total
FROM (
  SELECT SUM(price) FROM things WHERE stuff_id = ? GROUP BY stuff_id
) t
WHERE stuff.id = ?
```

This works fine when there are actually rows in `things`, but when not no UPDATE is executed (which I guess makes sense). What would be an elegant way to set `stuff.total` to `0` in that case? I'd like to do it in one query.
I already tried `SET stuff.total = coalesce(t.total, 0)` but it had no effect.

Comment: I'm confused. Your statement is syntactically wrong. `ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHERE"` Also, the `GROUP BY` seems redundant. Are you sure this is a postgresql question?

Comment: yes @fl0cke is right. Can you post your exact query please. For example in your subquery, the WHERE appears after GROUP BY which cannot be

Comment: thanks @fl0cke, in trying to redact domain specifics I accidently swapped the statements. That's now fixed.

Comment: @BrewerGorge  Does `?` match more than one id? If not, you can omit the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't used `coalesce` in the right place. Also, `GROUP BY` can be omitted. Try this query:

```
UPDATE stuff
SET stuff.total = t.total
FROM (
  SELECT coalesce(SUM(price), 0) FROM things WHERE stuff_id = ?) t
WHERE stuff.id = ?
```

Comment: When things is empty, this also returns 0 rows

Comment: this, combined with what @fl0cke said solved the problem. Thanks people!